# Largest three number with Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

The goal was to return a arr containing [34,9001,10000] However, I would get undefined

What is that I need to remedie and reasoning behind it.

```js
let array = [-9, 0, 34, 10000, -420, 6, 9001]

function findThreeLargestNumbers(array, arr = []) {

  if (arr.length === 3) return arr

  arr.unshift(Math.max(...array))

  array.splice(array.indexOf(Math.max(...array)), 1)

  findThreeLargestNumbers(array, arr)
}

console.log(findThreeLargestNumbers(array, []))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = [-9,0,34,10000,-420, 6,9001]

function findThreeLargestNumbers(array, arr=[]) {
    if ( arr.length === 3) return arr
    arr.unshift( Math.max(...array))
    array.splice(array.indexOf(Math.max(...array) ),1 )
    return findThreeLargestNumbers(array,arr)
}

console.log( findThreeLargestNumbers(array,[]) )
```

you just forgot to add return for the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

this is best answer of you question how many max you want from an array write count 1,2,3,4, ... n max from an array

```js
let array = [-9, 0, 34, 10000, -420, 6, 9001];

function maxN(array, count) { 
  if (count <= 0) return [];
  count--;
  const index = array.indexOf(Math.max(...array));
  return array.splice(index, 1).concat(maxN(array, count));
}

console.log(maxN(array, 3));
```